# Option to migrate proposed topics to another tag

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When dismissing a proposed topic, there should be an option for "this should belong to a different tag".  I think of this as similar to how a Stack Overflow question can be migrated to another SE site when it's off-topic.

For example, there is a request in the "C" tag for documentation on COM programming.  This should instead be a request in the "COM programming" tag for examples in the C language.  There's an "already exists" dismiss reason, but this doesn't help when that documentation doesn't exist yet (or in this case, the documentation tag is still in the proposal state).  It's a valid request so I'd rather not completely dismiss it as "not needed", but there aren't many options at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you see a proposed topic that is invalid or not useful, you just dismiss them. I just discovered that feature today.

Tons of people are suggesting adding topics for *libraries* to *language* tags. For C++, I see WinAPI, MFC, Qt, ffmpeg, etc. etc. The Objective-C language documentation is having a similar problem, I understand, with people trying to document iOS and macOS APIs.

[I leave a comment pointing to the documentation for the relevant tag, and then dismiss the proposal.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/topic-requests/3629)

Yes, it'd be nice if you could say "already exists" when dismissing and link to the tag documentation that does already exist, but this is not supported. It tells you that "Link does not point to a Topic" (as if this were German, and nouns were capitalized).

> [image]

If it's a *specific topic* being proposed that belongs in the documentation for that other tag, just dismiss it in the wrong place and re-propose it in the right place.

Comment: My problem's not with invalid or non-useful proposals, it's useful proposals that are in the wrong place.  That is, it's not useful within the context of the current tag, but it would be perfectly useful elsewhere.  I hate simply throwing them out when there's merit to them.  The submitter can always create a new one in a different place, but it would be a lot easier if the existing proposal could just be migrated over.